# Intuition and applications for the p-Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, intuition

Consider the p-Laplacian of a suitably nice function $u$:

$\Delta_p u = \nabla \cdot (|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u)$

Are there useful ways of thinking about the p-Laplace operator, or of thinking about p-harmonic functions (the functions $u$ with $\Delta_p u = 0$ in some domain)?

What are some application of the p-Laplacian that could help in building intuition for it?

-

Similar question for the Laplacian: [Intuitive interpretation of the Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One practical application of $\int |\nabla u|^p\to \min$ is in image denoising. If $u$ is the light intensity, then noise contributes to $|\nabla u|$. The easiest thing to do computationally is to decrease $\int |\nabla u|^2$, which more or less amounts to [Gaussian smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). Unfortunately, $\int |\nabla u|^2$ penalizes not only noise, but also sharp edges, which become blurry in the process.

Taking $p=1$ instead of $p=2$, we arrive at [TV denoising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising), which preserves edges. The drawback here is that the total variation functional is not strictly convex (bad for minimum search) and the associated Euler-Lagrange equation $\nabla \cdot (|\nabla u|^{-1}\nabla u)$ is awfully degenerate. One way around this is to minimize $\int \alpha |\nabla u| + |u-u_0|^2$, with $u_0$ being the noisy image.  This addition of the quadratic term makes the optimization process more palatable: see [here](http://jessica2.msri.org/attachments/10771/10771-Carter.pdf), for example.

On the opposite extreme, for large $p$, the $p$-Laplacian is used to model [growing/collapsing sandpiles](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=p-laplacian+sandpile&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33).

Answer (score 5):

Well, in a sense that's only useful for other mathematicians, it's about minimizing the $L^p$ norm of the gradient.

In general, you can think of it as another averaging differential operator: it has the form $\nabla \cdot (D \nabla u)$. In heat transport equations, D is the diffusion coefficient, which in this case is proportional to a power of the gradient.

There is also a detailed explanation of some of the physics background of the equation at Math Overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66418/on-the-physics-background-of-p-laplacian-equation)