# Interpretation of one-dimensional p-laplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation, p-laplacian

Do you know some interpretation or practical application of one-dimensional p-Laplacian systems (which is also an example of Euler-Lagrange system)$
\frac{d}{dt}(|\dot u(t)|^{p-2}\dot u(t))=\nabla W(t,u(t)),
$
where $\nabla W(t,u)$ is the gradient $W$ in $u$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $u\in\mathbb{R}^N$.
Or even more general system 
$
\frac{d}{dt} \nabla G(\dot{u}(t))=\nabla W(t,u(t)),
$
where $G$ is some convex, $C^1$ function?

We know that in pde's one practical application is image denoising [Intuition and applications for the p-Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188801/intuition-and-applications-for-the-p-laplacian)