$p$-Laplacian and the $\phi$-Laplacian
What does the the $p$-Laplacian operator in one dimension describes in apllied sciences where $\phi_p(x)=|x|^{p-2}x, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}$?
Is there any references where can find the history evolution of this operator?
thank you in advance for your response.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188801/intuition-and-applications-for-the-p-laplacian.
