# Why can we use $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in place of $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So I was looking at [this reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1888652/801288) to a question that was asked, and I kind of skipped a bunch of multivariable calculus in classes due to a thing and essentially learned most of what I could on my own, but I don't understand why we can just do the thing that I've mentioned in the question statement. Is it just that we're treating the derivatives as fractions or is there a proper reasoning for this? Could someone please explain?

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169942/why-can-partial-derivatives-be-exchanged

Comment: Ahhh yesss okay, looking at both of these right now and these seem to be making sense. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the general idea is that if a function is separable for its variables i.e.
$$f(x,y)=\sum_i g_i(x)h_i(y)$$
then the order of derivatives is interchangeable since:
$$\partial_x\partial_y(g_ih_i)=\partial_xg_i\partial_yh_i=\partial_y\partial_x(g_ih_i)$$
however I am still trying to find a reference for this

Comment: Why is a reference needed for this? All the steps are very straightforward.

Comment: Ahh yess I see. So I wanted to know the reasoning behind this, but this is helpful too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not always the case.
There are various ways of formulating the constraint for this to be the case.

There's an article about it on Wikipedia here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: It is not good answer I think.

Comment: Why? It's an entire article about mixing partial derivatives.

Comment: It is the content to be included in the comment, not the answer.

Comment: The link to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169942/why-can-partial-derivatives-be-exchanged actually refers to an answer that also has a blog post link for the same theorem, yet a little less complete than the above..

Comment: Thanks for this link as well, looking through it right now!