# Proving that the Laplace operator is rotationally invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, partial-derivative, laplacian

I'm trying to show that the Laplace operator is rotationally invariant. It's [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970892/show-laplace-operator-is-rotationally-invariant) to this topic, but I  can't seem to figure my mistake. I want to prove that:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}
$$
where:
$$
\begin{cases}
u=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\\
v=x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta
\end{cases}
$$
On one hand we get:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\sin\theta
$$
So we get:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\sin\theta\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\sin\theta
$$
Then:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\sin\theta\right)=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\sin\theta\right)=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\sin\theta
$$
Lets put it back together:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}=\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta\right)\cos\theta+\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\sin\theta\right)\sin\theta
$$

Now I want to do the same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cos\theta
$$
So we get:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}=\frac{\partial}{y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cos\theta\right)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cos\theta
$$
Then we get:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cos\theta\right)=-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cos\theta\right)=-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\cos\theta
$$
Lets put it together:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}=\left(-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta\right)\sin\theta+\left(-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\cos\theta\right)\cos\theta
$$

But, as I understand, in order to show $\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}$, I need to have:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}=\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\sin\theta-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta\right)\sin\theta+\left(-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\cos\theta\right)\cos\theta
$$

Because then I get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}&=\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\cos\theta\right)\cos\theta+\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\sin\theta+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}\sin\theta-\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u\partial v}\cos\theta\right)\sin\theta\\&=\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\right)\cos^{2}\theta+\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\right)\sin^{2}\theta\\&=\left(\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}\right)\left(\cos^{2}\theta+\sin^{2}\theta\right)\\&=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial u^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial v^{2}}
\end{align*}
$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: In my opinion you missed a minus sign when you put together for $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$... you wrote but then you missed it

Comment: @Davide Right! That's it!