# Physical Intuition for Mean Value Property of Heat Equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, heat-equation

I am trying to think of an intuitive explanation for the mean value property for the heat equation:

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{4r^2} \int_{E(x,t,r)} u(y,s) \frac{|y|^2}{|s|^2} dy ds$$

where $E(x,t,r)$ is the heat ball of radius $r
$ centered at $(x,t)$.

The analogous formula for the Laplace equation

$$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} v(y,s) dy$$

makes sense if you think of Laplacian as a local average (as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian/50285#50285)).

**My Question.** Is there a physical interpretation of the factor $\frac{|y|^2}{|s|^2}$?

I guess one can think of it in terms of "how fast information is propagating in space-time," but that still does not explain why the factor is squared...

I know that there are many questions of a similar title (such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075545/what-physical-information-does-the-mean-value-property-of-heat-equation-convey)), but as far as I know, none of them address my question.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3671432/305862