# An MO answer by Terry Tao regarding what the Laplacian measures

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

In his answer to an MO question: "[Why is the Laplacian ubiquitous?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54986/14319)", Terry Tao says that

> The Laplacian of a function $u$ at a point $x$ measures the average extent to which the value of $u$ at $x$ deviates from the value of $u$ at nearby points to $x$ (cf. the mean value theorem for harmonic functions).

Would anybody elaborate (probably with examples) how the mean value theorem for harmonic functions relates to the point he makes about the Laplacian?

Comment: See here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian/50285#50285

Comment: The mean value theorem for harmonic functions says that harmonic functions *don't* deviate from their local average, which matches up with their Laplacian being zero. When it is nonzero, there is deviation between them, and the sign tells you which one is bigger.