# In general, what information is given by $\nabla^2 f \geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Since there are many directions one can take when studying this equation, I am curious:

Given a function $f \in C^2$ defined on some open set, what information is given by $\nabla^2 f \geq 0$? Please let me know if I am missing something important for the question to make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of information are you interested in? For instance they are (I'm assuming you mean functions with a non-negative Laplacian) subharmonic, and in particular they satisfy the maximum principle.

Comment: See here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian/50285#50285

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of $\nabla^2 f\ge 0$: If it means that the Hessian matrix of $f$ is positive semidefinite, then $f$ is a convex function.