# Show that the Laplace equation is rotation invariant.

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $u(x)$ be a harmonic function in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $A$ an orthogonal matrix then I wish to show that $u(Ax)$ 
is also harmonic.
I understand how to do this by showing that
$$\triangle{u(Ax)}=0$$
But would like to show this using the Mean value property and believe that I need to show that

$$u(Ax)=1/\alpha(n)r^n\int_{B(x,r)}u(Ay)dy=1/n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}\int_{\partial{B(x,r)}}u(Ay)dS(y)$$
However, I cannot seem to get started on this at all.

Comment: Look at this:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/intuitive-interpretation-of-the-laplacian/50285#50285

Comment: Thank you Christian unfortunately due to my lack of expertise I am unable to progress.  Further direction would be appreciated.