# Why spatial diffusion is modeled by Laplacian?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, laplacian

Suppose that $p(x,t)$ be population density of some species at time $t$ in position $x$. Then the spatial movement is modeled by the Laplacian with diffusion coefficient $k$. I want to know, why Laplacian came into the picture here?

Comment: The short answer is: discretize space, calculate the flux through a segment of width $dx$, write an expression for total population in that segment, then let $dx \rightarrow 0$. The result is the laplacian. The long answer is long.

Comment: It arises under the assumption of [Fick's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion), i.e. that the rate of diffusive flow of the species is proportional to the density gradient. Wikipedia has [a derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Derivation_of_Fick's_laws) as well, although it's less intuitive than dbx's suggestion to consider the rate of in/out-flow for an infinitesimal volume.

Comment: @dbx when we write the expression for the total population, do we need to differentiate it?

Comment: The Laplacian is a local averaging at every point in the domain, which is exactly what diffusion is.

Comment: Thanks @mattos , that makes more sense to me.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50274/8157) contains the answer, even if it is not exactly a duplicate.